# Why does the output of comm fail to show common records?

Tags: text-processing, comm

I have a list of IDs (sorted) in two files and I ran the comm command to compare them, but it seems to miss out one lines common to both files. Why is that?

File1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
```

File2:

```
16
18
21
23
705
707
709
711
712
826
827
839
846
847
848
872
873
874
875
891
```

Comm output: `$> comm file1 file1`

```
1
    16  //exists in both files
    18  //exists in both files
2
    21
    23
3
4
5
6
7
    705
    707
    709
    711
    712
8
    826
    827
    839
    846
    847
    848
    872
    873
    874
    875
    891
9
11
12
13
15
16 //it's here!
17 
18 //...and here!
19
20
21
22
```

The files are both sorted. However, my guess is that `comm` doesn't do numeric comparison and only looks at entries lexicographically? If so, what are some alternatives that I can try for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`comm` should tell you that one of the files isn’t sorted:

```
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

It expects the files to be sorted using the current locale’s collation order (as determined by `LC_COLLATE`); it won’t accept numerical order.

To compare the files, you can pre-sort them (lexicographically as you point out):

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If you want the result to be sorted numerically, sort it again:

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sort -n
```

This produces

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
15
        16
17
        18
19
20
        21
22
    23
    705
    707
    709
    711
    712
    826
    827
    839
    846
    847
    848
    872
    873
    874
    875
    891
```

Comment: The files ARE in sorted order...have a look at the snippets.

Comment: As far as `comm` is concerned, `file1` *isn’t* sorted: it expects files to be sorted in lexicographical order, not in numerical order.

Comment: I *had* run the commands I gave you, as I always do. I’ve added the output. Note you missed 21 which is also common to both files.

Comment: I see - so even if they are sorted, it needs "lexicographical ordering" only to do its job correctly. Interesting nuance :)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my comment above; I’ll add that to my answer, for clarity.